# NextJS13: React seems to be always taking initial state in useEffect and forgets the other state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

**TLDR / Summary of the issue that I am facing:**

I am working with a Nextjs 13 project with the experimental app directory and I am facing an issue with useEffect. I have two main states `page` and `pageSize`.

React seems to update only one of the states at a time and seems to forget that I have previously set the state of the other one. Furthermore, the other state is always going back to the initial initialized state.

**Details:**

The way I am implementing this whole thing is based on setting the URL with the NextJS13 router on the frontend with client components with main logic written in client component `Pagination.jsx` and then the child components `ComponentA.jsx` and `ComponentB.jsx` render the selcts which control these two states with onChange handlers defined in `Pagination.jsx`.

I am making the fetch request in a parent Component `BlogPage` i.e. `page.jsx` which wraps around `Pagination.jsx`, which is a server component.

**Code Details:**

I am updating the states of the `page` and `pageSize` with the help of HTML select elements, which in turn calls the `handlePageChange` and `handlePageSizeChange` onChange. I am able to confirm that these handler functions are getting triggered.

Default value for `page` state is 1 (First Page) and default value of `pageSize` is `defaultCategoryPageSize` which is set to 10 in the server component.

**The issue:**

When I first change the select corresponding to "page", it triggers the handlePageChange method which in turn sets the state for the page(Let's say I set it to 3). Now I change the select corresponding to the "pageSize" and it triggers the handlePageSizeChange method,  which in turn sets the state for the pageSize(Let's say I set it to 30).

Now based on the logic I expect the `useEffect` to be run twice(once for each select as they trigger an updation of the states which I have added in the dependency array) and then update the query variable, which in turn sets the `queryPath` variable used to modify the route.

**However, instead of getting:**

```js
query = {
page: 3
pageSize: 30
}
```

**I get :**

```js
query = {
page: 1
pageSize: 30
}
```

And when I do it the opposite way, where I load the initial /blog route and set the pageSize to 30 first with the help of the corresponding HTML select element and then set the page to 3, the query becomes

```js
query = {
page: 3
pageSize: 10
}
```

Instead of the expected:

```js
query = {
page: 3
pageSize: 30
}
```

What is going on and why is this happening?

### Code for reference:

#### Pagination Component (Client Component):

```
// src/helpers/Pagination.jsx:
"use client";

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { PaginationContext } from "@/context/pagination/PaginationContext";

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
require("dotenv").config();

const Pagination = ({ children, defaultCategoryPageSize }) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(Number(defaultCategoryPageSize)); // Initial value
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1); // Initial value

  const handlePageSizeChange = (event) => {
    console.log("handlePageSizeChange is runnning");

    const newSize = parseInt(event.target.value);

    // Update the state with the new page size
    setPageSize(newSize);
  };
  const handlePageChange = (event) => {
    console.log("handlePageChange is runnning");

    const newPage = parseInt(event.target.value);
    // Update the state with the new page size
    setPage(newPage);
  };

  /**
   * The useEffect which is going to get triggerred whenever
   * the pageSize or page states change and update the URL.
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    let query = { ...router.query }; // Clone the existing query object

    let DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE = Number(defaultCategoryPageSize);

    if (pageSize !== DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE) {
      query.pageSize = pageSize; // Update the pageSize parameter
    } else {
      delete query.pageSize; // Remove the pageSize parameter if set to the default value
    }

    // If page is 1 then don't have query.page in the query
    if (page !== 1) {
      query.page = page; // Update the page parameter
    } else {
      console.log("Test to check if the page is becoming equal to 1");
      console.log(page);
      delete query.page; // Remove the page parameter if set to the first page
    }

    console.log(
      "The current Query parameter that is going to be set in the query Path is:"
    );
    console.log(query);

    let queryPath = "?" + new URLSearchParams(query).toString();

    console.log(queryPath);

    router.push(queryPath, { shallow: true, scroll: false });
  }, [pageSize, page, defaultCategoryPageSize, router]);

  return (
    <>
      <PaginationContext.Provider
        value={{
          page: page,
          pageSize: pageSize,
          handlePageChange: handlePageChange,
          handlePageSizeChange: handlePageSizeChange,
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </PaginationContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
};

export default Pagination;
```

#### Component A (for page Select)

```
// src/shared/ComponentA.jsx
"use client";

import { useContext } from "react";

import { PaginationContext } from "@/context/pagination/PaginationContext";

function ComponentA() {
  const { page, handlePageChange } = useContext(PaginationContext);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="component-a__container ">
        <h1 className="text-cyan-300">Component A State : Page Value</h1>
        <div className="select__container flex flex-row gap-2">
          <label htmlFor="component-a__select">Page Value:</label>
          <select
            name="component-a__select"
            value={page}
            onChange={handlePageChange}
            id="component-a__select"
          >
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default ComponentA;
```

#### Component B (for pageSize Select)

```
// src/shared/ComponentB.jsx:
"use client";

import { useContext } from "react";

import { PaginationContext } from "@/context/pagination/PaginationContext";

function ComponentB() {
  const { pageSize, handlePageSizeChange } = useContext(PaginationContext);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="component-b__container">
        <h1>Component B State : Pagintaion Value</h1>
        <div className="select__container flex flex-row gap-2">
          <label htmlFor="component-b__select">Page Size Value:</label>
          <select
            name="component-b__select"
            value={pageSize}
            onChange={handlePageSizeChange}
            id="component-b__select"
          >
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="50">50</option>
            <option value="70">70</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default ComponentB;
```

#### Create Context File:

```
// src/context/pagination/PaginationContext.jsx:
import { createContext } from "react";

export const PaginationContext = createContext({ page: 1, pageSize: 10 });
```

#### Server-Side Main Parent Component:

```
// src/app/blog/page.jsx:
import ComponentA from "@/shared/ComponentA";
import ComponentB from "@/shared/ComponentB";
import useStateFullLogic from "@/helpers/useStateFullLogic";
import Pagination from "@/helpers/Pagination";

function BlogPage() {
  //   const { handlePageChange, handlePageSizeChange } = useStateFullLogic();
  console.log("Hello where am I running?");

  return (
    <>
      <div className="blog-page--container flex flex-col gap-6 container">
        <h1 className="text-3xl my-5">Blog Page</h1>
        <Pagination defaultCategoryPageSize={10}>
          <ComponentA />
        </Pagination>
        <h3 className="text-lg">Some Random Content in between</h3>
        <Pagination defaultCategoryPageSize={10}>
          <ComponentB />
        </Pagination>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default BlogPage;
```

**Any help is appreciated, I have been scratching my head as to why it is only updating the latest dependency in useEffect and not remembering the other value. Thank you.**